# How do I fix the position of elements in css regardless of the window size?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, position, css-position

I am trying to set boxes so I can add other elements accordingly. However the positions of these boxes keep changing depending on the monitor I'm using or if I go on full screen mode on my browser.

I tried using relative units (vh, vw) for the margins but that didn't help. Here is my html and css:

```css
.main {
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  height: 1036px;
  width: 1280px;
  padding: 0 96px 0 96px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  z-index: 3;
  margin: 0 300px 0 300px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.header {
  position: relative;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 1036px;
  width: 528px;
  z-index: 3;
  border: 2px solid white;
  padding: 35px 0 66px 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<section class="main">
  <section class="header">
  </section>
</section>
```

Comment: Not too sure what you are trying to achieve with that. Do you have some sort of drawing you could provide? Or can you explain in a bit more detail?

It also looks like you're mixing `position` with `display: flex` whereas I'd be inclined to use either/or for a layout.

Do you want to fix the position of the header in the `main` section or is it that you want to fix the position of `main` relative to the body?

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to achieve here. You're using a lot of fixed values for height and width. While those are fine, you aren't going to fill the width of the page or get consistent experiences for every browser/viewport size. I'd need to understand padding, margin, and width numbers to help you figure this out. Could you explain the goal again or provide a screenshot? Is the point to have the `.main` fixed in the viewport? Tell me more about why things have the positioning and z-index that they have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying to create some sort of fixed layout for your components. I think the problem is coming in cause of the fixed values you are using and misuse of position and display: flex. Try using this css code maybe it might work for you `

```
.main {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 5%;
  border: 2px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.header {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  left: 10%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 60%;
  width: 40%;
  border: 2px solid white;
  padding: 3% 0 6% 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

`am very sure the issue is with fixed units Vs relative units